# Nilpotent elements in a quotient of a polynomial ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, nilpotence

I'm trying to prove the following statement. I'm not entirely sure if it's true though I suspect it is:

> Consider the ring $A = \mathbb Z[x]/(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$. Then the element $x \in A$ is nilpotent if and only if $x$ is nilpotent in $A \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{F}_p$ for all primes $p$ and $x$ is nilpotent in $A \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Q}$.

One direction is obvious. For the other direct I've been trying to fiddle around with the correspondence theorem to obtain that $x$ is the the nilradical of $A$ to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $I:=(f_1,\dots,f_n)$. Since $x$ is nilpotent in $I \iff x\in \underset{\underset{\mathfrak{p}\supset I}{\mathfrak{p}\text{: prime ideal}}}{\bigcap}\mathfrak{p}$, if $x$ is not nilpotent there exists a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ that does not contain $x$. If $\mathbb{Z}\cap \mathfrak{p}=(p),p$ a prime number, $x$ is not nilpotent in $A/\mathfrak{p}=A/\mathfrak{p}\otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{F}_p$ and not in $A\otimes \mathbb{F}_p$. If $\mathbb{Z}\cap \mathfrak{p}=0$, $x$ is not nilpotent in $A/\mathfrak{p}$ and not in $A\otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Q} \subset \mathrm{Frac}(A/\mathfrak{p})$.

Answer (score 1):

In fact I came up with a nice argument for the general fact. The general result follows from the specific case above by considering the map $\mathbb Z[x] \to A$ picking out the element $a$, but let's prove it in general just for fun.

Let us prove:
Let $A$ be a commutative ring. Then $a \in A$ is nilpotent if and only if $a$ is nilpotent in $A \otimes \mathbb Q$ and $A \otimes \mathbb F_p$ for each prime $p$.

Let $a \in \Gamma(\mathrm{Spec} A)$. We want to prove that $a$ is in every prime ideal. Pick a prime ideal  $\mathfrak p$ and consider $A_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak p$, the residue field at $\mathfrak p$. The map $A \to A_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak p$ factors through $A \otimes \mathbb F_p$ or $A \otimes \mathbb Q$ (depending on the characteristic of the residue field). In any case, there exists an $n(\mathfrak p)$ with $a^{n(\mathfrak p)} \otimes 1$ vanishing in one of these. But this means that $a^{n(\mathfrak p)}$ vanishes in $A_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak p$ which is equivalent to $a^{n(\mathfrak p)} \in \mathfrak p$ which is equivalent to $a \in \mathfrak p$. Since $\mathfrak p$ is arbitrary we are done.

Comment: What does $\Gamma\left(\operatorname{Spec} A\right)$ mean? Just the set of all prime ideals of $A$?

Comment: And just to spell it out: The "general fact" is the claim for all commutative rings $A$. Wondering whether it also holds when $A$ is noncommutative...

Comment: @darijgrinberg suppose we want to show an element a in nilpotent. To consider the image of a in A is to consider the subring of A generated by a, which is precisely the image of this polynomial ring, which is necessary a quotient by a finite set of polynomials, since Z and thus Z[x] is Noetherian. The notation $\Gamma(\mathrm{Spec A}) $ just means A, but I wrote it in a fancier way because the second argument is more geometric.

Comment: @darijgrinberg, I think the results holds for general rings too, by the reduction to the polynomial case.

Comment: Aaah, why this notation?

Comment: I'm not sure how the general ring case could be derived from the polynomial case. Tensor products don't have to be particularly well-behaved over a non-field.

Comment: The reduction is like this: $a \in A$ is nilpotent precisely if it is nilpotent in the smallest subring of $A$ containing $a$. But this subring is by definition the image of $\mathbb Z[x] \to A$. But this is isomorphic to a polynomial ring of the form in the original question. Notice we haven't assumed that $A$ is commutative in this case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146202/discussion-between-jordan-levin-and-darij-grinberg).